# The results of xy coordinate transform in R and arcmap are different

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r

Some lon lat sites were converted to xy geographic coordinates in R (target geographic coordinate system `EPSG:102012`) :

```
     lon   lat
1 120.11 50.15
2 121.41 50.29
3 117.19 49.35
4 119.42 49.15
5 119.56 47.10

lonlat <- data.frame(lon=c(120.11,121.41,117.19,119.42,119.56),
                     lat=c(50.15,50.29,49.35,49.15,47.1))

inproj <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
outproj <-  '+proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=105 
+x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'

coordinates(lonlat) <- c(1,2) 
proj4string(lonlat) <- inproj
xy <- as.data.frame(spTransform(lonlat,outproj))
xy
        lon     lat
1 1033208.0 5981950
2 1117747.6 6014440
3  848573.9 5862626
4 1006104.0 5867861
5 1056140.0 5654292
```

I added these lon lat points (WGS84 projection) to arcmap as shape points and changed to geographic projection. Then using `Calculate Geometry` in attribute table.The xy coordinate got as follows:

```
1033208.041 5981950.466
1117747.601 6014439.722
848573.8694 5862626.143
1006103.956 5867860.72
1062292.81  5684395.771
```

`inproj` Lambert_Conformal_Conic(LCC) ESRI WKT projection in arcmap:

```
PROJCS["LCC_WGS_1984",GEOGCS
    ["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM
       ["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID
       ["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
       UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
       PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
       PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],
       PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],
       PARAMETER["central_meridian",105.0],
       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30.0],
       PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",62.0],
       PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0],
       UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

The results of first four sites are same between two methods, but there is bias in fifth point. That puzzle me.

Origin of this problem: I want to extract raster values to points.Fake codes as follows:

```
xy <- spTransform(lonlat,crs(raster)) 
values <- raster::extract(raster,xy)
```

I found some points values were NA. So I checked the point spatial distribution that overlap `shape points` and `raster` in arcmap. All points are in raster. but some the coordiates tranformed in R were out of raster. That is why the extracted values are NA.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the Esri projection engine. I get 1056139.98 5654291.83. If I unproject the numbers you got, I get 119.72 47.366. Maybe double-check the coordinates of the feature?